# Cannot send or receive any emails by using Cpanel after I updated the nameserver to amazon Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, cpanel, amazon-ses

I registed the domain name in WHC website and changed the namesever of the domain to the nameserver that generated by Amazon router 53.
The domain is online now but i cannot receive or send any emails by using Cpanel.
someone suggested me to use Amazon SES service to fix this problem.
I associated the SES to my domain and route 53, and added new TXT and CNAME records to the Cpanel setting. but the problem still there.

Comment: If you post your old DNS configurations before moving to Route 53, we could try to help you.

Comment: Check /var/log/exim_mainlog and see what's the exact error (if you have WHM access).